# How to run the mlflow web-based user interface from Amazon SageMaker?

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, mlflow

I want to use the mlflow web-based user interface from a notebook on Amazon SageMaker. But the given address http://127.0.0.1:5000 doesn't seeem to work.

I have installed mlflow on a SageMaker notebook.

This code runs nicely:

```
import mlflow
mlflow.start_run()
mlflow.log_param("my", "param")
mlflow.log_metric("score", 100)
mlflow.end_run()
```

And then if I run

```
! mlflow ui
```

I get the expected result:

```
[2019-04-09 11:15:52 +0000] [17980] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
[2019-04-09 11:15:52 +0000] [17980] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:5000 (17980)
[2019-04-09 11:15:52 +0000] [17980] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2019-04-09 11:15:52 +0000] [17983] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 17983
```

However, after that when going to `http://127.0.0.1:5000` in my browser, nothing loads.

My guess it that `127.0.0.1` is not the right address, but how can I know which address to use instead?

Comment: Did you try replacing `127.0.0.1` with Sagemaker notebook instance url - https://myinstance.notebook.us-east-1.sagemaker.aws/?

Answer (score 5):

Hi and thank you for using SageMaker!

Unfortunately, it appears that mlflow isn't compatible with SageMaker at this time.  We do provide a feature that can support these scenarios.  SageMaker includes a plugin called [jupyter-server-proxy](https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyter-server-proxy) which allows other web applications to be hosted on your SageMaker Notebook Instance, such as TensorBoard.

In the case of mlflow, I was almost able to get your example working by visiting `https://mynotebookinstance.notebook.us-east-1.sagemaker.aws/proxy/5000/` (notice how the port number is moved to the end), but unfortunately mlflow displays an error since it currently assumes that it is not running at the root URL path.

I've created an issue in the mlflow GitHub repo: https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/issues/1120  Please "Star" this issue to keep up-to-date on its status.

Best,
Kevin

Comment: did you able to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve the issue by port-forwarding instead of using the proxy link.

In the local terminal, run the following command:

```
ssh -N -L 5000:127.0.0.1:5000 ec2-user@your_sagemaker_instance_ip_address
```

And then just go to http://127.0.0.1:5000